# Responsive site displaying too small in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Similar question have been posted here, but I've none of the solutions presented there help me. I have a site: http://cherryfieldmaine.us/
When I test the site with Firefox Responsive Design View, or other online responsive testing tool, the site looks fine - just as it should. However, when I view it on a real iPhone, the site fills up less than 1/2 of the screen.

I've never encountered this before and I'm at a loss for how to fix it. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you share screen shot?

Comment: I tried with my code i think its looking fine
i share my screen shot.This is iPhone 5s simulator
Dropbox link :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/031btrgmtody5ga/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2023-Feb-2016%2010.21.35%20am.png?dl=0

Comment: It looks correct in all of the simulators, but not on any iphone I've tried (I've not tried in on an android. Here's a snapshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXxOUGkmxsgWjNzQ2Z0ZXBDNm00NFBRREowMjBmM0gzVEk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: which device do you use?coz i also tried with my real device its looking fine.i have iPhone5.
here is the scree shot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnvjkxed130zrhr/IMG_4459.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I got it.Its problem occurs in safari browser.If you can use UIWebView than its looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://cherryfieldmaine.us/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```